# Cómo recibo datos "data-value" en laravel 5

Tags: html, laravel, formularios

Tengo una consulta, tengo un formulario carga preguntas con un `foreach` en *blade*, de esta forma:

```
<form action="{{route('tests.store')}}" class="text-center" method="post">
    @csrf
    @foreach($questions as $question)
    <div class="form-group">
        <br>
        <label for="question">{{$question->question}}</label>
        <br>
        <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-value="5">5</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-value="4">4</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-value="3">3</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-value="2">2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-value="1">1</button>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 py-5 border d-flex">
                    <ul class="pagination mx-auto">
                        <li class="page-item">
                            {{$questions->render()}}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Terminar</button>
</form>
```

En el controlador que recibirá los datos debo conseguir el valor que está en "`data-value`" de cada botón, cómo se puede hacer? Gracias de antemano.

Pd: Esos datos van a función store de una controlador de recursos de laravel.

Comment: no es un atributo que se propague por post o get, tendrías que leerlo y pasarlo al endpoint con javascript ( form submit, tomar los valores armar un formdata y enviarlo), o duplicar el valor en otros input hidden (como propone la respuesta de Aarón)

Answer (score 0):

Este problema tiene muchas soluciones, una de ellas podría ser que pongas un `<input type="hidden">` por cada pregunta y que con Javascript, jQuery, Vue o lo que estés usando, settees el valor.

Un enfoque:

Podrías darle otro atributo a tu botón que te permita acceder al input hidden de cada pregunta, ejemplo `<button type="button" data-inputHidden="{{ $question->id }}" data-value="1">` y tu input hidden sería: `<input type="hidden" name="answers[]" id="pregunta-{{ $question->id }}">`

Ejemplo con jQuery

```
function clicBtn(){
  $('.btn-pregunta').on('click', function(e){
      var id = $(this).data('inputHidden');
      var valor = $(this).data('value');
      $('#pregunta-'+id).val(valor);
  });
}
```

De esta forma, tendrías un input por cada pregunta con la respuesta seleccionada y se enviaría al servidor, y ya tu manejarías la demás lógica.

Aunque yo diría que deberías de utilizar radio buttons para este tipo de casos y darles estilo.